# Can OpenGraph elements be shared among different applications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a bunch of Facebook applications that will have to use the same set of Open Graph concepts (actions and objects)...

Do I need to define them repeatedly for each app or can they be defined in one app and reused in the others?

The [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial) seems a little bit ambiguous about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´d say it will not work, because of the different domains (you do have to set an URL in the developer settings). Also, afaik it´s somewhere in the Facebook rules that you are not allowed to use one and the same app for different pages/purposes.